# How to add legend to Matplotlib for cluster data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I add legend to the plot over in my scenario? the parameter of text is the `text = tfidf.transform(document)` and the parameter of clusters are the unsupervised clusters ranging from 0 to 19 clusters and have their bag of words. How do I add the legend to the plots? It is indistinguishable that which color corresponds to which cluster.

```py
def plot_tsne_pca(data, labels):
    max_label = max(labels)
    max_items = np.random.choice(range(data.shape[0]), size=3000, replace=False)
    
    pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(data[max_items,:].todense())
    tsne = TSNE().fit_transform(PCA(n_components=50).fit_transform(data[max_items,:].todense()))
    
    
    idx = np.random.choice(range(pca.shape[0]), size=3000, replace=False)
    label_subset = labels[max_items]
    label_subset = [cm.hsv(i/max_label) for i in label_subset[idx]]
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 6))
    
    ax[0].scatter(pca[idx, 0], pca[idx, 1], c=label_subset)
    ax[0].set_title('PCA Cluster Plot')
    
    ax[1].scatter(tsne[idx, 0], tsne[idx, 1], c=label_subset)
    ax[1].set_title('TSNE Cluster Plot')


plot_tsne_pca(text, clusters)
```

Here is the full example of the code: https://pastebin.com/3PABg7xh
[image: Plot]

[image: Not commenting out label_subset = [cm.hsv(i/max_label) for i in label_subset[idx]]]

[image: Commenting the label subset out.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `legend_elements()` to automatically return the lists of artists/labels (or a subset thereof) for legend creation. See [Automated legend creation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#automated-legend-creation) for more details

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import offsetbox
from sklearn import (manifold, datasets)

digits = datasets.load_digits(n_class=6)
X = digits.data
y = digits.target

tsne = manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, init='pca', random_state=0)
X_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(X)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(X_tsne[:,0], X_tsne[:,1], c=y, cmap='tab10')
ax.legend(*sc.legend_elements(), title='clusters')
```

[image]

**EDIT**

In your particular case, the code was not working because `legend_elements()` is meant to be used when you have a mapping between a numeric `c=` list and a colormap. But instead, you were passing a list of colors that you constructed by hand (`label_subset = [cm.hsv(i/max_label) for i in label_subset[idx]]`). If you remove that line and keep a numeric `label_subset` and map it to colors using `cmap=` then everything works as expected

```py
def plot_tsne_pca(data, labels, sizelist, cmap='tab10'):
    max_label = max(labels)
    max_items = np.random.choice(range(data.shape[0]), sizelist, replace=False)

    pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(data[max_items, :].todense())
    tsne = TSNE().fit_transform(PCA(n_components=1).fit_transform(data[max_items, :].todense()))

    idx = np.random.choice(range(pca.shape[0]), sizelist, replace=False)
    label_subset = labels[max_items]
    #label_subset = [cm.hsv(i / max_label) for i in label_subset[idx]]
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 6))

    ax[0].scatter(pca[idx, 0], pca[idx, 1], c=label_subset, cmap=cmap)
    ax[0].set_title('PCA Cluster Plot')

    sc = ax[1].scatter(tsne[idx, 0], tsne[idx, 1], c=label_subset, cmap=cmap)
    ax[1].set_title('TSNE Cluster Plot')
    ax[1].legend(*sc.legend_elements(), title='clusters')


plot_tsne_pca(text, clusters, sizelist)
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, that is not working for some reason. It only shows a key with title clusters but has no numbers and color assigned to it. I have added this to my code:
```sc = ax[1].scatter(tsne[idx, 0], tsne[idx, 1], c=label_subset)```
```ax[1].legend(*sc.legend_elements(), title='clusters')```

Comment: Then your will need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a toy dataset. Something that can be copied/pasted exactly and reproduces the problem you are having.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3PABg7xh. This is a working example of the code directly.

Comment: Thanks for the MCVE. I've tracked down the issue and updated my answer

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question about this problem. When commenting that part out, the clusters can not really be identified by the algorithms color scheme now. This is a weird result then.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot help any further. I don't really understand your code. I don't understand why you are taking two random sampling `max_items` and `idx` and then magically end up with something that looks right